# Synonyms for "speak of the devil [and he doth/shall appear]"

Tags: idioms, synonyms

Specifically, I'm looking for something that would fit in the same situation, but I need a less negative connotation. Saying that when my Dad, for instance, walks into the room while I'm talking about him, well, that sort of seems to imply I think he's the devil.

Naturally, any help or criticism of my question is welcome. I can't improve if I don't know something's wrong.

Comment: This may just be a personal thing but I use it all the time and the idiomatic use of it never seems to have the negative connotations, particularly if you say it with a genuine smile. :D

Comment: The expression's literal translation is also present in Hindi. For the positive turn, we use a different expression- (We were just talking about you, therefore:) you're gonna live a long life.

Comment: My grandfather often said "speak of the devil and in he walks" if someone who was a recent topic of discussion arrived.

Comment: @Catija that's a reasonable point, and is probably a contributing factor to why I'm able to use this expression with my dad. I just want something more appropriate to say in general usage or with someone that I don't want to take a chance of them misunderstanding. So Jeff's answer is pretty good. Just wish I got more responses; maybe I accepted his answer to soon?

Answer (score 5):

Not a direct replacement, but something you might say *to* your Dad when he comes in: "Were your ears burning?" See [Origin of burning ears](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161919/origin-of-burning-ears) if you are not familiar with the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Its so much better in Spanish. What you say is "Speaking of the King of Rome, and there he comes!"

Comment: Is that used in English?  Many languages have similar sayings, but we don't use the direct translations for the expression.  Please include a source and do take a moment to see the [help].